# Можно ли связать клик мышью с использованием технологии COM НА Windows?

Tags: windows, com

Я загрузил .torrent в браузере и нажал на иконку программы mTorrent в окне этого же браузера.

Вот так это выглядит:

[image: открытие .torrent файла]

Могу ли я предположить, что в данном случае будет использована COM (ТЕХНОЛОГИЯ)?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен, но в целом - да

Comment: Во-первых, надо уточнить значок упомянутой программы существут всегда или только при загрузке соответствующего файла - т.е. является ли функционал программы расширением к браузеру? Во вторых, не ясно о каком браузере идёт речь? Ведь расширение браузера может быть реализовано через Chrome Extension API, а может даже и через ActiveX. И, собственно, не понятно по тэгам вопроса, какая тема Вас интересует: безопансость, разработка расширений, автоматизация действий пользователя и т.д.?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае используется технология или Chrome Native Bridge или http запросы на апи запущенного клиента, а также сочетание этих технологий. Через Натив вызывается плагин , который запускает клиент, а потом устанавливается связь или по хттп с расширением или по другому IPC (среди которых может быть COM, но врятли) с плагином.